# Stream Video On Android Like YouTube

Tags: java, android, youtube, video-streaming, android-video-player

I want to play video on my android app with a player like YouTube. 
My webapp is using videojs for playing different video formats.

I dont wish to use the native media player on android as i want to show portrait version of it and show the likes and comments beneath the video.

Currently am using a webview on the half of the layout and below that am using the layout for likes, comments etc.

So, What should i go for ? I want to use the player like YouTube. Is it even possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java) Might be able to provide you some info on it, it contains the API for youtube

Comment: Not as far as I can see